# I am not able to follow link in x-ray scraper and fetch the data

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, x-ray

```
      x(url,some_scope,{
        'title':'title',
        'desc': x('.coloriginaljobtitle a@href',{
            desc: '.desc',
            apply_link:'.applyBtnTopDiv a@href'  
        }) 
    })

    //callback for this xray
    ((err, result)=>{
        console.log(result)

    });
```

this is my actual code in xray scraping I can't follow link to next page. Wee heres the catch i can manuaaly scrape that link and scrape data but not able to follow that particular links. im just geting title not sub part .i.e desc and apply_link